# Approximation of $f(x, y)$ by $\sum_{n=1}^N c_n \chi_{A_n}(x) \chi_{B_n}(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lp-spaces

I believe the following statement is true, but I cannot prove it.
I would be grateful for your advice.

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and let $(X \times Y, \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}, \mu \times \nu)$ be product measure space. Define
> \begin{equation}
> D := \left \{\sum_{n=1}^N c_n \chi_{A_n \times B_n} \mid N \in \mathbb{Z}_+ , c_n \in \mathbb{C}, A_n \in \mathcal{A} , B_n \in \mathcal{B}\right \}.
> \end{equation}
> Then, $D$ is dense in $L^p(X \times Y; \mathbb{C})$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sketch.  You already know that the set $D' := \big\{ \sum c_n \chi_{E_n} : E_n \text{ is $(\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B})$-measurable} \big\}$ is dense in $L^p(X \times Y)$.  Then just use the fact that the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$ is generated by sets of the form $A \times B$ where $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$.  This allows you to conclude that any $(\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B})$-measurable set can be approximated up to an arbitrarily small error by a finite union of sets of the form $A \times B$.  This then implies that $D$ is dense in $D'$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, how can I prove that "any $(\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B})$-measurable set can be approximated up to an arbitrarily small error by a finite union of sets of the form $A \times B$" ?

Comment: You can find a proof of it in section 5.7 of [this book](https://www.stat.colostate.edu/~estep/assets/chapters5-6.pdf)